# How can I preload an image to later set it as a background-image with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover, preloading

I am trying to preload an image so when I need to set it as a background image, it's ready and it won't load during the CSS transition. I tried to do it using the AJAX load() method, but I think I should be able to do it without AJAX. I am not sure something like this would work since I don't need a img tag or src, but something like storing the direct URL of the background image so I can later set it as a background-image.

```
var img = new Image(); img.src = 'img.jpg';
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#LogoContainer').hover(function() {
    $('#LogoMainPart').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
    $('#LogoOtherPart').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $('#Introduction').css('background-image', 'url(hoverbackground.jpg)');
}, function() { 
    $('#LogoMainPart').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $('#LogoOtherPart').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
    $('#Introduction').css('background-image', 'url(background.jpg)');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the image object with

```
var myImage = new Image();
```

Assign the src of that image which will load the image into the browser cache like so:

```
myImage.src = 'my-bknd.jpg';
```

Now that it's in the browser cache you can add it to the DOM whenever you choose like so:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.background = 'url(my-bknd.jpg)';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so simple and it works! I am using a CSS linear transition for the hover background-image animation and it works when I hover, but not on mouse out. Do I have any option to apply the reversal transition in CSS or should I go directly for a jQuery fading? I am not sure I can do that with background images.

Comment: @AdrianaCota Even though animating background opacity in css is not widely supported because it is not a css standard (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css) there is a way you can get around this.  Here is a pen (http://codepen.io/haltersweb/pen/QNPVLq) where I created a content div with a child div to act as the background.  When you hover on the content div the bknd div transitions opacity over 1 sec.  When you mouseout the transition goes in reverse.  the hover state is on the parent and the opacity transition is on the child.